P-channel MOSFET output operation with gate resistors
I have the following circuit:

When R4 is 100 kΩ, my Vgs voltage is -1.0727 V, which is not low enough to turn on the FET.
However, when I change R4 to 5 kΩ, Vgs is -7.87 V and now I am able to see full voltage at Vout.
Can anybody explain how this works at a deeper level?

VGS = - Vin * R1/(R1  + R4) = - 11.8V * 10/110 =  - 1.0727V The voltage divider is the answer.

Resistors R1 and R4 simply work as a voltage divider, while D1 prevents Vgs from going above 10 V.

Typically a switch or a bipolar NPN transistor is placed instead of R4 and switched by an MCU IO pin, to turn the MOSFET on. The R1 turns it off when there is no R4, the switch is open or the NPN transistor is off.

With 10k and 100k and 11Vin, you have about 1.0 V across the 10k resistor ==> that's the -VGS of the FET.
You basically need to exchange the 2 resistors.
The zener is used to protect the FET against excessive voltages -- e.g. if VIN became 20 V -- the zoner would limit VGS to just 10 V.
R1 is used to return VGS to 0V when R2 is removed (open circuit).

You have a pair of resistors (R1 and R4, though I'll call them R1 and R2 here) in series, with a potential difference (voltage) applied directly between their two ends, as follows:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This arrangement of resistors is called a "resistor voltage divider", because the total applied voltage will be shared between them in proportion to their resistance. In words, each resistor will develop a voltage in proportion to its resistance, as a fraction of total resistance \$R_1 + R_2\$. That means:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R1} &= V_{TOT} \times \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} \\ \\
V_{R2} &= V_{TOT} \times \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
You'll notice that Kirchhoff's Voltage Law is always obeyed:
$$ V_{R1} + V_{R2} = V_{TOT} $$
In the left and middle circuits above, \$R_1=10k\Omega\$ and \$R_2=100k\Omega\$, as you have in your original schematic. The fraction of the total voltage adopted by each resistor is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} &= \frac{10k\Omega}{10k\Omega + 100k\Omega} = 9.1\% \\ \\
\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} &= \frac{10k\Omega}{10k\Omega + 100k\Omega} = 90.9\% \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Check for yourself that the voltmeters are showing values that correspond to these.
Since your MOSFET's source is connected to node S, and its gate is attached to G, \$V_{GS}\$ is the potential difference \$V_G - V_S\$,  the voltage across R1 negated. The middle circuit above represents your own setup:
$$ V_{GS} = V_G-V_S = -V_{R1} = -1.073V $$
That agrees with your own simulated results. I hope its clear that if you wish to "switch on" your MOSFET, then it's sufficient to swap R1 and R2, as I have done in the right-most circuit above. Then you will have:
$$ V_{GS} = V_G-V_S = -V_{R1C} = -10.73V $$
A derivation of the above formulae goes as follows:

simulate this circuit
By Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL), current \$I\$ is the same all around the loop, so both resistors share the same current. By Ohm's law, the voltage across each resistor will therefore be:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R1} &= IR_1 \\ \\
V_{R2} &= IR_2 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
By Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (KVL), the sum of the voltages across the resistors must equal the total applied voltage \$V_S\$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R1} + V_{R2} &= V_S \\ \\
IR_1 + IR_2 &= V_S \\ \\
I(R_1 + R_2) &= V_S \\ \\
I &=  \frac{V_S}{R_1 + R_2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Substituting this expression for \$I\$ into the Ohm's law equations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R1} &= IR_1 \\ \\
&= \frac{V_S}{R_1 + R_2} \times R_1 \\ \\
&= V_S\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Similarly for R2:
$$ V_{R2} = V_S\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} $$
These are only true if no current is sunk or sourced at the junction of the resistors. The MOSFET's gate will not source/sink current (at DC) since its gate is extremely high impedance. This is not the case, however, for the zener diode, which will begin conducting heavily as voltage \$V_{R1}\$ across it approaches 10V. This will effectively prevent \$V_{R1}\$ from exceeding 10V, which can be demonstrated by sweeping applied voltage upwards from zero, while plotting \$V_{R1}\$ and \$V_{R2}\$:

simulate this circuit
Note that I am plotting \$V_{SG}=V_S-V_G\$, to keep both traces positive. Also note how KVL is always obeyed, and that at all times (even when \$V_S\$ exceeds 10V) \$V_{R1}+V_{R2}=V_S\$:

